# Pulling data from multiple tables codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to get data from 3 tables using left join and where clauses, if i join two tables it shows record but when i join third table it does not pull record don't know why

```
public function get_customer_detail_4_withdraw($customer_id) {

        $query = $this -> db -> select('*')
                             -> from('deposits')
                             -> where('deposits.customer_id', $customer_id)
                             -> join('customers', 'deposits.customer_id=customers.id', 'left')
                             -> where('withdraw_deposit.customer_id', $customer_id)
                             -> join('withdraw_deposit', 'withdraw_deposit.customer_id=deposits.customer_id', 'left')
                             -> get();
        return $query -> result();

    }
```

Comment: echo & check query with the help of : echo $this->db->last_query(); afterwards copy and paste same in phpmyadmin and execute. Check resultset matching with CI resultset

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to re-arrange joins and where.

For example :

```
public function get_customer_detail_4_withdraw($customer_id) {

    $query = $this -> db -> select('*')
                         -> from('deposits')
                         -> join('customers', 'deposits.customer_id=customers.id', 'left')
                         -> join('withdraw_deposit', 'withdraw_deposit.customer_id=deposits.customer_id', 'left')
                         -> where('deposits.customer_id', $customer_id)
                         -> where('withdraw_deposit.customer_id', $customer_id)
                         -> get();
    return $query -> result();

}
```